# my android app crashes when calling getWritableDatabase(); method

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I just found out that when I try calling the `getWritableDatabase();` method and run it, the app crashes. I  called that method only to test if `onCreate` method will run but before it can call `onCreate` it get stuck at `getWritableDatabase`.

```
    package com.mycompany.database;
    import android.database.sqlite.*;
    import android.content.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.sql.*;

    public class DBmanager extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        public static final int database_version=9;
        public static final String database_name="testDB";
        public static final String table="tblAMIGO";
        public static final String key_name="name";
        public static final String key_id="recID";

        public DBmanager(Context context)
        {
            super(context, "sdcard/"+database_name, null, database_version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase DB)
        {
            DB.execSQL("create table tblAMIGO(" + " recID integer, " + " name  text );  "    );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase p1, int p2, int p3)
        {
            p1.execSQL("drop table if exists "+table);
            onCreate(p1);
        }

        public void addName(String id, String name)
        {
            //I get the error only when I implement this method
            SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();

            db.execSQL("create table IF NOT EXISTS tblAMIGO(" + " recID integer, " + " name  text );  "    );
            ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
            values.put(key_name, name);
            values.put(key_id, id);

            db.insert("tblAMIGO",null,values);
            db.close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi... I am unable to post my logcat for I am using AIDE for android... but can I atleast ask you how to change path to sdcard if I use waqaslams idea?? Because his idea corrects the problem but change the database path name to default...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing a custom path may cause the problem since checking the availability of path is not done prior to it's creation. To make it simple (default), change the code in constructor as below:

```
super(context, database_name, null, database_version);
```

Comment: Thanks @waqaslam for answering my question... Yes that should work, but is there a way for me to change its path to sdcard like i did before?

Comment: Yes, for that you may experiment with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` and other related calls to hold path of your sd card. But make sure you do also check that the SD card is mounted before doing any operation on it.